# Scraping Info from YouTube

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to scrape the category of a video from YouTube and I've encountered some issues with the handling of data. As of now I've been trying to set a delay and then going through the possible links to create an HTML collection and then iterating through that.

However, when I iterate through the collection, some of the values are different when the loop is executing and logging to the console as compared to the HTML collection elements.

Specifically, the element of the collection that has the category is logged differently in the script's loop.

My code is about as follows:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("more-button style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer")[0].click()
    console.log("in the conditional")
    categories = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string");
    console.log(categories);
    console.log("checking category");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(categories, function (category) {
        console.log(category.innerText);
        if (category.innerText == "Entertainment" || category.innerText == "Gaming" || category.innerText == "Comedy") {
            isBadCategory = true;
        }
    });
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!